# Company wants to take pictures of me as I do a programming test

Tags: applications

I'm looking for a job change, so I was browsing Indeed and applied to a few jobs. Shortly after applying to one company, I got an email from them asking me to take a C# test. No big deal, I thought. However, I noticed the testing site (TestDome) wants to take pictures of me while I take the test. This just sounded creepy right off the bat. I haven't even spoken or exchanged emails with the company yet. I don't think this is normal, and I'm not going to take the test because of it, but I wanted to get your opinion. This is the email:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a particular question/concern we can address? While not very common, this type of thing does happen. I've taken many online technical tests with various verification and/or anti-cheat measures, and yes: at least one of them took periodic pictures of me.

Comment: They want to be sure you don't get someone better than you to do this for you...

Comment: I don't really like a machine taking photos of me periodically while I'm taking a test. It seems like either an unwanted distraction or invasion of privacy in a way. But, if I really need a job, I will still take this test anyway because other candidates will have to go through the same process.

Comment: Yes, it's creepy, and a hard pass on the job.  After all, if they want to do that when you are interviewing, what are they going to do when you are an employee?

Comment: And of course this is really unnecessary.  If they can't tell by talking to you afterwards that you know what you are doing, you probably don't want to work for them.  For example, "what alternatives did you consider instead of using X?".

Comment: @DaveG "really unnecessary" is a matter of opinion. I'd think the part of the point of an online test is to weed out candidates who clearly can't do the work. If you have to arrange an interview with them and have one of your devs take time out of the day, just to catch that, I'm not sure the online test is worth it.

Comment: @mattfreake Obviously you aren't going to have your devs conducting the first interviews.  But equally obviously if you are hiring a dev, you are going to have a dev talk to the candidate later on, in order to check whether the candidate will really fit and to get more detail, right?

Answer (score 8):

This is standard for exam situations, such as for Microsoft online exams for Gold partnership accreditation. Pearson VUE who partner with Microsoft to deliver these exams have the [following requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/online-exams) before you take the exam

> Exam area scan
>
> Prior to starting the exam, ensure that all additional monitors are
> unplugged and turned away from you, and any other computers are turned
> off and monitors are dark.
>
> The work area should be clear of all materials, and the following are
> not allowed within arm's reach: books, notepads, Post-it notes, typed
> notes/papers, or writing instruments such as pens, markers,
> whiteboards, or pencils.
>
> A mobile phone works best for capturing the required exam area photos,
> but you can use a webcam if you don’t have a mobile phone. If you use
> your mobile phone, the pictures are uploaded and a greeter will review
> them along with your headshot and ID. The greeter is looking for
> security risks and will notify you if anything needs to be addressed
> prior to launching the exam.

The company that is looking to hire you obviously feel they have a need to enforce the same rules. Perhaps they have had candidates who have passed their test but have then gone on to underperform, which can be costly. Or someone else took the test for the candidate, which can have a disastrous outcome.

In my workplace, we have an online test where we stay on the call with the candidate for an hour whilst they work on their solution. We don't encourage the use of online articles to support the outcome, but it's not a reason to terminate the interview.

Let's be realistic, a significant proportion of developers use sites like Stackoverflow to help them overcome obstacles; that's the entire point of Stack sites.

Comment: Wow, no writing instruments/paper/whiteboard during an exam is a hard pass for me. I'm a big fan of working out problems on paper/whiteboard.

Answer (score -3):

Some academic institutions started doing this for exams, to prevent cheating. It doesn't work well, and particularly if you are not white there is a very good chance that you won't be able to complete the test anyway.

This shows that the company does not trust applicants to be honest. You should ask yourself if you want to work for a company like that. Personally, I would decline, and in fact I tend to decline if they set exams at all since they are a very poor measure of ability.

Try applying for jobs with more experience, they tend to be less suspicious as applicants will have an established track record.

Comment: Some academic institutions have experimented with eye/gaze-tracking software that uses the laptop webcam, to prevent cheating on digital exams during Covid lockdowns. Many such products were not tested with a sufficiently diverse set of participants. https://web.archive.org/web/20210410021225/https://www.theverge.com/2021/4/8/22374386/proctorio-racial-bias-issues-opencv-facial-detection-schools-tests-remote-learning

Comment: Sorry, have lots of results of students who look away from the screen and the software picks them up - has **nothing** to do with color.

Comment: @SolarMike The problem is that most such software is just tested on white men.  End result is you may see false results from a different set of people.  See https://www.newscientist.com/article/2161028-face-recognition-software-is-perfect-if-youre-a-white-man/

Comment: Racial bias in facial recognition technology is a known defect. The periodic snapshots will most likely be run against a software will be just as biased. This is entirely valid points.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I thought you were asking for context on the race comment, but I now understand you were intimating that “user’s” race comment didn’t fit the description given by OP.

Comment: Not trusting _employees_ is a bad sign in a company; not trusting _applicants_ is entirely reasonable. Screening out dishonest applicants is a necessary part of the process.